# Less expensive query?

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure that returns an integer 1 or 0 depending on specific criteria.  It currently uses three select statements and it will be used heavily by multiple users across multiple locations.  There has to be a more efficient way of doing this.

In short the query checks first to see if all checklist items on an order are completed (a separate table), then it checks to see if a field named BreakOutGuest (a bit field) is a 1 or 0.  Depending on that result it checks to see if the total guest count is greater than 0 and the order total is zero.  It returns the one or zero on all this criteria.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?  A temp table so I only have to hit the actual tables once?  Below is the code.

```
@ORDERID INT

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @AUTO_CLOSE INT



    SET NOCOUNT ON;

--If all checklist items are marked complete move on, if not set @AUTO_CLOSE=0
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ORDERID FROM dbo.orderchecklistitems WHERE OrderID=@ORDERID AND CompletedON IS NULL)
BEGIN

--if BreakOutGuestFees is 1 only sum Guest_Count_1 + Guest_Count_2
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Orders  WHERE (GuestCount_1 + GuestCount_2)>1 AND OrderTotal=0 AND BreakoutGuestFees=1)

BEGIN
SET @AUTO_CLOSE=1
END
ELSE 
SET @AUTO_CLOSE=0
--if BreakOutGuestFees is 0 only consider Guest_Count_1
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Orders  WHERE (GuestCount_1)>1 AND OrderTotal=0 AND BreakoutGuestFees=0)
BEGIN
SET @AUTO_CLOSE=1
END
ELSE
SET @AUTO_CLOSE=0

END
ELSE 
SET @AUTO_CLOSE=0

END
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the search by `OrderID` in the other two accesses to the `Orders` table? And why isn't this just a single `select` that returns `1` or `0`?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I altered the actual stored procedure to remove sensitive info before posting in a public forum and I accidentally removed the "and O.OrderID=@ORDERID" clause on the second two select statements but it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If am not wrong you can combine two `if` clause into single `if` clause by using `AND` , `OR` logic. Try this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ORDERID
              FROM   dbo.orderchecklistitems
              WHERE  OrderID = @ORDERID
                     AND CompletedON IS NULL)
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT *
                FROM   dbo.Orders
                WHERE  ( ( GuestCount_1 + GuestCount_2 > 1
                           AND BreakoutGuestFees = 1 )
                          OR ( BreakoutGuestFees = 0
                               AND GuestCount_1 > 1 ) )
                       AND OrderTotal = 0
                       AND OrderID = @ORDERID)
        SET @AUTO_CLOSE=1
      ELSE
        SET @AUTO_CLOSE=0
  END
ELSE
  SET @AUTO_CLOSE=0
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  All the solutions suggested worked, I ended up using NoDisplayName's solution with a few minor alterations that fit our specific coding protocols.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform your selection check with only one query

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT sum(1) FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ORDERID FROM dbo.orderchecklistitems WHERE OrderID=@ORDERID AND CompletedON IS NULL)),
    (SELECT sum(1) FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Orders  WHERE (GuestCount_1 + GuestCount_2)>1 AND OrderTotal=0 AND BreakoutGuestFees=1)),
    (SELECT sum(1) FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Orders  WHERE (GuestCount_1)>1 AND OrderTotal=0 AND BreakoutGuestFees=0))
    INTO
    result1, result2, result3
    from dual
```

then check results

Comment: Also, OP's code looks like T-SQL. You don't need (or have) `dual` on MS SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELCARE @AUTO_CLOSE INT = 0

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ORDERID
              FROM   dbo.orderchecklistitems
              WHERE  OrderID = @ORDERID
                     AND CompletedON IS NULL)
  BEGIN
      SET @AUTO_CLOSE = 
        (
            SELECT 
                CASE
                    WHEN (GuestCount_1 + GuestCount_2 > 1) AND BreakoutGuestFees = 0 THEN 1
                    WHEN (GuestCount_1 > 1 ) AND BreakoutGuestFees = 1 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END
            FROM dbo.orders
            WHERE OrderTotal = 0 AND OrderID = @orderID
        )
  END
```